# JSON object value pass to NodeJS server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, handlebars.js

I want to update MySQL Database using JSON object values in NodeJs and Handlebars. I have created the JSON successfully. That JSON includes only `id` and `updated_order`. Now I have to do use the  `updated_order` value and update it using `id` value for where clause.

But I am getting an error when trying to this.

> 500 Internal Error upOrders is not iterable

Button -->

```
<form id="skuFormorders" method="post" action="/productorder">
  <button id="update_order" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" style="background-color:white" onclick="xxx.prepUpdateOrder();">Yes</button>
</form>
```

Create a JSON object in products.handlebars -->

```
xxx.getUpdateOrderJson = function(){
var jsonObj = [];
var id = '';
var existing_order = '';
var updated_order= '';
var updated_row='';
jQuery("table tbody tr").each(function (index, value) {
    id = $(value).find('.orderid').data("value");
    existing_order = $(value).find('.exsorder').data("value");
    updated_order = (index+1);
    updated_row = {}

    if(existing_order != updated_order){
      updated_row ["id"] = id;
      updated_row ["updated_order"] = updated_order;
      jsonObj.push(updated_row);
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
};

xxx.prepUpdateOrder = async function (e) {
  $('#upOrders').val(xxx.getUpdateOrderJson());
  document.getElementById('skuFormorders').submit();
});
```

Output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));` ->

```
[{"id":2,"updated_order":1},{"id":3,"updated_order":2},{"id":1,"updated_order":3}]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(req.body.data)`

Comment: @Barmar When using this code `const x = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  console.log(x);` I am getting this error  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: What is the name of the `#upOrders` input in the form? `data` should be that name.

Comment: If it's `name="upOrders"` then you should be using `req.body.upOrders`.

Comment: @Barmar I used `console.log(JSON.parse(eq.body.upOrders));` for cosole the output. Then I am getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: eq is not defined`. If you can post as an answer It will be a big help me.

Comment: You have a typo, `eq` should be `req`

Comment: @Barmar Then `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` is shown as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Based on your form's HTML, I can see that you do not have an input with and id of `upOrders`, so your data is not getting attached and therefore the `req.body` is `{}` (an empty object).

Add an input to the form so that your jQuery can append the updated order to the submitted data:

```html
<form id="skuFormorders" method="post" action="/productorder">
  <input type="hidden" id="upOrders" name="upOrders" />
  <button id="update_order" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" style="background-color:white" onclick="xxx.prepUpdateOrder();">Yes</button>
</form>
```

---

First, make sure you are using the `body-parser` middleware for you server to handle form submissions. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Your error is saying that the `req.body.data` is not iterable. This is because you are setting the value of your form element to be a JSON string:

```js
$('#upOrders').val(xxx.getUpdateOrderJson());
```

So, most likely `req.body` has a property named "upOrders" (or whatever the "name" attribute of the "#upOrders" element is) that you would then need to call `JSON.parse` on:

```js
let upOrders = null;
if(req.body.upOrders) {
  upOrders = JSON.stringify(req.body.upOrders);
} else {
  throw new Error('Request is missing "upOrders"');
}
```

This is making a lot of assumptions about how you are sending the form data to the server, and how your server is processing the data. To get the exact attribute that you need to call `JSON.parse` on, you should inspect the contents of `req.body` and find the property that your data is stored in.

Comment: When I using the above code It shows a an error. It is `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request is missing "upOrders"`

Comment: Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));` before `let upOrders = null` and paste the results here.

Comment: Then I am getting this error. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request is missing "upOrders"`

Comment: try changing the `else` block to be:
`throw new Error('Request is missing "upOrders"\n' + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, '\t'));`
and tell me what the error isafter that.

Comment: Here is an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request is missing "upOrders"
{}`

Comment: It looks like the body of your request is not getting populated with the data you are sending. Check out https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: `const app = express();`
`app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`
`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

Comment: In my application above things are using

Comment: Can you include the HTML of your form?

Comment: Yes I can include the HTML of my form.

Comment: Ok, please add it to the original question.

Comment: I added HTML part.

Comment: I updated my answer with a potential solution @found_iuo

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much for your commitment to this.

Comment: @found_iuo my pleasure!